# Make ID attribute HTML5 <section> PHP dynamical

Tags: php, html, attributes, sections

Im trying to get  dynamic with php. And I wonder if this is possible. However i pass a $var to ID the section does not show up. Lets say I have this:

```
<?php
$var = "welcome";

$html = '<section id="'.$var.'">Im glad you are here</section>';

echo $html;
?>
```

So this is the basic thing and I cant find any other reference to this. Note: Im writing this from my phone so forgive me if there is a syntax error.
Thanks in advance and wish you a good day.

Comment: The `Im glad you are here` is not showing in the browser?

Comment: From where `$var` it came?

Comment: No, nothing at all, the whole section is gone, and looking on the browser site source code the section tags are not there. Thanks for the edition @Sirko, since Im in the phone I couldnt format it.

Comment: I just tried this,  disregarding the error,  `Im glad you are here` appeared in my browser

Comment: Is `$var` a typo?

Comment: Everything works perfect according to the code in the question. You've got the `Im glad you are here` and empty `<section id="">`

Comment: I voted for close the question. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing I see is there is a mismatch between your variable name and the variable you pass.

Variable decaration is as **V**
then you pass **var**

Comment: Although there will be an `undefined` error, `<section>` should still appear

Comment: Section is appear. At least on my end when I test the code `<section id="">Im glad you are here</section>`

Comment: Well thanks for your answers guys, I think I need to post my script but now Im away. I will post it later. thank you all, Ill come back soon.